# renaming .xib file in Xcode 4.3.3 is this the right way?

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4.3

I wanted to rename the files .h, .m. .xib into my own name.

I have created a tabbed application, and I did single click on the source browser, and changed

```
FirstViewController.h to FVC.h
FirstViewController.m to FVC.m
```

and changed respective places to include FVC.h.

It works for me. But what i would like to know is that is this the right approach that i can go ahead with?.. will there be any hidden issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "gotcha" is that if you are using the nibName in your code (ie initWithNibName:), you obviously need to change that too. I personally have gotten bit with that problem - the app launches then crashes when it tries to push that broken object.

Comment: Here's a nice way to do it more simply: http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/14/how-to-rename-a-class-using-refactoring-in-xcode-4/

Comment: @ObjectiveFlash is absolutely correct - use 'Refactor' in the left Xcode pane! Totally missed this.